# Python, IndexError: list assignment out of range (g[ng]floatinput(": ")). How do I fix this?

Tags: python, for-loop, indexing, while-loop

I'm new to programming and my current assignment for my class requires us to enter the number of students, enter grades for each student (-1 to stop), then display a grade report. My problem is this error message...IndexError: list assignment out of range(g[ng]floatinput(": ")). How do I fix this? 
If there is another way to go about this, I am open to suggestions!

```
#Input number of students
s=int(input("How many Students are there?: "))
print("=================================================================")

#create list of student grades
for n in range(s):
    g=[0]
    t=0
    ng=0
    ns=0

    print("Enter Student # ",n+1," scores (-1 to stop enter scores):")

#Input grades 
    while g!=-1:
        ng+=1
        print('Grade#', ng, end='')
        g[ng]=float(input(": "))
        ng+=1
    print("=================================================================")
    print("Student #",n+1,"Grade Report")

#Index and recall grades
    for r in g:
        print('Grade#',r+1,':\t',r,end='') 
        if r<60:
            print("\tF")
        elif 60<=r<70:
            print("\tD")
        elif 70<=r<80:
            print("\tC")
        elif 80<=r<90:
            print("\tB")
        elif 90<=r<100 or r>100:
            print("\tA")

#Print average for grades          
    print() 
    if 0<=(t/(ng-1))<60:
        print("Average: ", format(t/(ng-1)), "Your grade so far is F")
    elif 60<=(t/(ng-1))<70:
        print("Average: ", format(t/(ng-1)), "Your grade so far is D")
    elif 70<=(t/(ng-1))<80:
        print("Average: ", format(t/(ng-1)), "Your grade so far is C")
    elif 80<=(t/(ng-1))<90:
        print("Average: ", format(t/(ng-1)), "Your grade so far is B")
    elif 90<=(t/(ng-1))<=100 or (t/(ng-1))>100:
        print("Average: ", format(t/(ng-1)), "Your grade so far is A")
    print("=================================================================")
print("=================================================================")
print("Grade report for your class done!")
```

Comment: There is one issue to start with  `while g!=-1:` would always be true as g is a `list` and -1 is an `int`

Comment: You cannot append to a list simply by assigning to an index beyond the last known element. Use `g.append(float(input(": ")))` instead.

Comment: Thanks,I am now able to input the grades, but I am unable to end my while loop. I need to be able to input -1 to stop the loop. Is it still possible to do so although g and -1 are different datatypes?

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently a student myself and I completely understand how frustrating loops can be at first. To answer your question, I believe part of your problem traces back to your input grades loop:

```
while g!=-1:
    ng+=1
    print('Grade#', ng, end='')
    g[ng]=float(input(": "))
    ng+=1
print("=================================================================")
print("Student #",n+1,"Grade Report")
```

You are incrementing ng twice.  Notice that you have two lines that have ng+=1. This means halfway through your list, you will be referencing an index that doesn't exist since you are doubling your ng (ng = 2, 4, 6, 8...)  instead of increasing it by 1 (ng = 1,2,3,4) as you probably intended.

Comment: Hm, I didnt see that. I changed that now but I am still getting the same error message.